# Implementing Unobtrusive Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm reworking an old website and am focusing on making the Javascript/jQuery as unobtrusive as possible. I'm looking for some advice on one part of the project: UJ requires that, if Javascript is turned off in a browser, all the site content is still available to the user. One part of my site has a large list of items. Each item in the list has it's own description, which uses CSS display:none to hide it by default. Clicking on the item toggles the visibility of the description using jQuery .toggle():, so a person unable to use Javascript (for whatever reason) would never see it. If I use Javascript/jQuery rather than CSS to hide the descriptions, they are all momentarily visible when the page loads, which I want to avoid. So what's the best solution?

Comment: Show us a little bit of the code of the list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically you can insert a class "no-js" in your `html` element, like so

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
```

and if javascript is enabled on the client you soon remove that class (using [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) or a simpler code snippet like

```
<head>
    <script>
    (function(d) { 
         d.className = d.className.replace(/(^|\b)no-js(\b|$)/, 'js');
    }(document.documentElement));
    </script>
    ...
</head>
```

in this way you can avoid the [FOUC (flash of unstyled content)](http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/) simply using `.no-js` and `.js` class in the css rules like so:

```
.yourlistitems { 
   display: block; 
}
.js .yourlistitems { 
   display: none; 
}
```

this approach is also used by [H5BP](http://html5boilerplate.com/) 
Note that you don't really need to prepend `.no-js` class to each rule: thinking in terms of "progressive enhancement" and "unobtrusive javascript" you will code and style first for a page that also works without javascript, then you will add functionality (and style specificity, prepending the `.js` class)

Comment: Thanks - that works perfectly. Could you please explain what exactly the /(^|\b) and (\b|$)/ in the function do?

Comment: that regular expression looks for an exact class "no-js" that doesn't belong to another class as a substring (like xxxno-js or no-jsxxxx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a method like the one implemented with Modernizr?

CSS classes are added to the HTML tag by a script that causes different CSS selectors to match.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--
    Putting this script in the head adds the "js" 
    class to the html element before the page loads.
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        document.documentElement.className = "js";
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*
        Only apply the hidden style to elements within the HTML element
        that has the js class
        */
        .js .description {display:none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="description">Example</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell if this really helps because of potential asynchronous operations but you might add a `<script>` which prepends your `<style> with display: (block|inline|whatever)` in which you toggle all relevant display to `none !important` by using plain JS, not jQuery.

So in case of JS the CSS display setting will be overridden beforehand.