# How can I stop my div appearing for a couple of seconds and disappearing?

Tags: javascript, css, html, getelementbyid

I maintain a website for the company I work for and just yesterday it somehow developed a problem i've not been able to solve. I've googled my bum off and can't find a solution. The problem is that we have three 's at the bottom of our page which should only show when you click on their relevant link (an unordered list of three links, each link loads a javascript show/hide function). But since yesterday, all three 's show for about 2 seconds and then disappear which is very annoying!! They shouldn't show at all unless clicked.  The website is at www.successphotography.com - have a look for yourself! Any help would be greatly appreciated.
relevant code:

```
<ul class="moreInfo">
<li onclick='swappy("graduation")'>Graduation Photography</li>
<li onclick='swappy("school")'>School Photography</li>
<li onclick='swappy("family")'>Family Photography</li>
</ul>
<div id="graduation">
<--- lots of content here --->
</div
<div id="school">
<--- lots of content here --->
</div>
<div id="family">
<--- lots of content here --->
</div>
```

The javascript for the swappy function is:

```
    window.onload=function(){

if (document.getElementById("graduation")) { 
    document.getElementById("graduation").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("school").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("family").style.display = 'none';

    }
}
function swappy(myself){
    switch(myself){
        case("graduation"):
            document.getElementById("graduation").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("school").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("family").style.display = 'none';
        break;
        case("school"):
            document.getElementById("graduation").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("school").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("family").style.display = 'none';       
        break;
        case("family"):
            document.getElementById("graduation").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("school").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("family").style.display = 'block';      
        break;
        default:
            document.getElementById("graduation").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("school").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("family").style.display = 'none';
        break;
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the style of the divs in the CSS? If you want them to not appear when the page is loaded then set them as `display:none` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you hide your div only when `window.onload` event occurs and this may take of course some time, depending on how much elements you have to load in page, latency, rendering and so on.

To avoid the Javascript FOUC (Flash of unstyled content) you should hide `#school` and `#family` elements via css instead, but when js is not enabled you won't be able to access anymore the content of those div. So take a look at this discussion: [implementing unobtrusive javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062811/implementing-unobtrusive-javascript/9062956#9062956)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already making use of jQuery, consider using the ready handler:

```
$().ready(function(){ /* code to hide elements here */})
```

rather than your current `window.onload=function`

This will execute your function when the document is ready, rather than once the window has loaded and may eliminate the flicker you're seeing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The golden rule here is this:

you should configure / build your CSS and JS such that your front-end shows (@ initial load) exactly the same with JavaScript enabled and without Javascript.

This way you never get the wiggly wobbly loading response.

Quick fix: initially hide the divs with CSS (display: none)

Comment: I don't think this is the best advice. With JS disabled, you want the hidden boxes to be showing. The content should be accessible to the user with JS either enabled or disabled. Hiding it with CSS removes this possibility for non JS enabled users.

Comment: @JamieDixon That's what `noscript` tags are for.

Comment: than you just make them `display: none` in a js function called exactley after they are created. that way the load time of the page won't affect the time until the onload starts and they get hidden.

Comment: @Jivings How would you impliment noscript in this scenario? Would you duplicate the HTML for this section or do something else? I'm intregued in how this would be implimented.

Comment: Thanks, i've used your quick fix until I implement a non-intrusive version that will work with both CSS and javascript